# Email from HTML file with WCF Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

Please help me.
I can't transform the HTML file to a string variable.
I tried this but in WCF doesn't work.
Thanks so much.

```
/// another service
SWCorreoServicioClient cMail = new SWCorreoServicioClient();

string subject = "test";
string body = string.Empty;

// This line doesn't work
body = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Doc/index.html"));

cMail.sendMail=("mailto@example", subject, body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution...
Instead

```
body = File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Doc/index.html"));
```

I made this:

```
string path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Doc/index.html");
body = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

And that was all. :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).